# Is it possible to stop UISearchBar from scrolling within UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

For example: The UISearchbar within UITableView like of the iphone Address Book app scrolls with the the names.

Is it possible to stop it from scrolling so it stays on top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the searchbar `out of table view` if you dont want to get it scrolled.

Or you can add the searchbar to the `header of section 0` instead of table header. boths gonna work.

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up adding a view and droping the searchbar and tableview onto it.

Comment: thats what i have told u as one option.. `Setting the searchbar out of tableView` Any ways good that your work is done... getting a vote is the best thanks :P